# OR 00904 error, how can i resolve this, is my date format wrong

Tags: oracle, ddl

this is my livesql code, getting errors like OR 00904

```
    '''
      create table customer(
          custno varchar2(10),
          lenddate DATE,

          constraint customer_custno_PK primary key(custno)
           );

          insert into customer(custno,lenddate) values('C12345','2015-12-12');

       '''
```

Comment: are you sure about `varchar2`?

Comment: The error message clearly indicates you are using Oracle, not MySQL. I re-tagged your question